# What does this Javascript code mean?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a algorithm challenge. I saw this code from one of the completed answers. I am new to javascript so I am not completely sure of the code. I know that the first section of code pretty much takes the input and makes it to a map. Then init a matchingPair array and a counter. I am pretty much lost at the for loop section. Not too sure what `matchingPairs[""+c[i]] = matchingPairs[""+c[i]] || 0;` does. I am guessing the for loop is adding all the elements of matching pairs to the array and adding to counter.

```
function main() {
var n = parseInt(readLine());
c = readLine().split(' ');
c = c.map(Number);

var matchingPairs = {};
var matchingPairCount = 0;

for(var i=0; i< c.length; i++) { 
    matchingPairs[""+c[i]] = matchingPairs[""+c[i]] || 0;
    matchingPairs[""+c[i]] += 1;

    if (matchingPairs[""+c[i]] % 2 === 0) {
        matchingPairCount += 1;
    }
}
console.log(matchingPairCount);
```

}

Comment: try `var x = {}; x['a'] = x['a'] || 0; console.log(x);` to see what happens - of course, the next line could be incorporated into this too ... `x['a'] = (x['a'] || 0) + 1`

Comment: @Andy.W Do you know python? `x['a'] || 0` behaves like a `defaultdict` evaluating to `0` when there is no property `a` (or when the property evaluates to `false`). `'' + x` is short for `String(x)`.

Comment: Out of interest is this a challenge website? If so which one?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler example

```
a = {}
a["b"] = a["b"] || 0
console.log(a) // {b: 0}
```

`a` is set to an empty object. `a["b"]` is not yet set  to anything, so when accessed it returns `undefined`.

Undefined is falsey - so this effectively sets `a["b"]` to `0`.

Take another example;

```
a = {b: 5}
a["b"] = a["b"] || 0
console.log(a)  // {b: 5}
```

The only difference in this example is that `a["b"]` is truthy (ie, it returns 5 rather than undefined).

This is a javascript way of setting a variable to a value **only if it hasn't already been set to something else**.

Answer (score 0):

A string of space delimited numbers is supplied.

The counts of each number are calculated.

Each time a count is even then the `matchingPairCount` is incremented.

In short: it is counting pairs of matching numbers.

`n` is not used?